# Markdown broken

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

What is wrong with the markdown prettifier here?

```
opts = {
   "$dollar$" :> "$",
   "$percent$" :> "%",
   };
```

Just to clarify the issue only appears on mathematica.stackexchange like it does [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94349/how-can-we-accommodate-arbitrary-unicode-characters-in-symbol-names?noredirect=1#answer-94354).

Comment: Not broken. It is an intentional bug because `$` opens a LaTeX cell and even if you are in a code-block, it still leads to the undesired behavior you see.

Comment: @halirutan should I change it to discussion?  IMO it a bug though.

Comment: I believe your post is a duplicate of my own: [(529)](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/529/121) -- please review and confirm or disagree.

Comment: It is not hard to edit the markdown in your posted answer to align the code nicely. I have done it for a few misaligned items in your answer to demonstrate how it is done. I didn't do a complete edit because it make your link unintelligible.